# BeautifulSoup trying to get selected value scraping IMDB but getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imdb

I'm trying to get the selected value from following HTML using BeautifulSoup but unable to.

```
<select id="bySeason" tconst="tt0944947" class="current">
  <!--
  This ensures that we don't wind up accidentally marking two options
  (Unknown and the blank one) as selected.
  -->
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
  <!--
  This ensures that we don't wind up accidentally marking two options
  (Unknown and the blank one) as selected.
  -->
  <option selected="selected" value="8">
    2
  </option>
</select>
```

This is what I am trying but in vain.

```
season_container = page_html.find_all("select", class_="current")
print(season_container.find_all('option', selected=True))
```

Comment: Could you please link the specific page you're working on?

Comment: It was IMDB Game of Thrones episodes page. 
response = get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/episodes')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow your search by selecting using `id`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<select id="bySeason" tconst="tt0944947" class="current">
  <!--
  This ensures that we don't wind up accidentally marking two options
  (Unknown and the blank one) as selected.
  -->
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
  <!--
  This ensures that we don't wind up accidentally marking two options
  (Unknown and the blank one) as selected.
  -->
  <option selected="selected" value="8">
    2
  </option>
</select>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
selected_value = soup.find("select", {"id":"bySeason"}).find("option",selected=True)

print(selected_value.get_text(strip=True))
print("-------")
print(selected_value["value"])
```

Output:

```
2
-------
8
```

Comment: This is even closer to my solution. Thanks this worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

```
season_container = page_html.find_all("select", class_="current")[0] # <- first ele. 
print(season_container.find_all('option', selected=True))
```

The first row returns an array so you have to specify to select (presumably) the first element.
The other part of the code is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it works. I didn't know I had to specify indexes too.